# Meaning of the word "blue" in song lyrics

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, lyrics

Can anybody tell me what the word "blue" means here?
And how can it make the protagonist get high/low?

> Little girl, little girl
> You should close your eyes
> That **blue** is getting me high
> And making me low

I found out that there is an English verb ["to blue"](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=to%20blue&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) which doesn't really make sense here. Maybe it refers to her blue *eyes* and *getting high* has to do with love.
That's what I thought so far.
[Find source here.](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/marilynmanson/heartshapedglasseswhentheheartguidesthehand.html)

Comment: Questions about song lyrics often tend to get close votes, so don't be too surprised if this question gets closed. (It's nothing personal – a few of the answers at [this meta question](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1302) explain why.) Your guess is as good as any.

Comment: I don't agree at all, even if this doesn't seem to matter on SE. In my opinion, it is important to especially talk about "not standard English" things. You learn a lot from them. However, I understand that this wasn't your point.

Comment: Just to be clear, I'm not dismissing the value of talking about such things, and you should feel free to do so in a chat room (even an SE chat room). But SE questions are supposed to lead toward definitive answers, not generate disputes that are inevitably mere matters of opinion.

Comment: Talking about your second sentence only. From my point of view, that is simply not true. Have a look at other posts where explanations for phrases/phrasal expressions are expected. This, at least for me, is about the same as lyrics, since there is a lot of context interpretation and regional background.

Comment: Just to be clear, my comment yesterday was meant to explain why this question *might* get closed. So far, it hasn't garnered a single close vote, which is fine with me. But one never knows how the community will react. Because I saw this yesterday right after you posted it, I just wanted to give you a heads-up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Song lyrics are often complex, because (like poetry) they try to evoke emotion with layered meanings.

First, let's look at "getting me high, and making me low".  To "get high" means to reach a state of euphoria or bliss, often through the use of drugs. Conversely, to be "low" means to be depressed, dejected, or diminished. In context, it means "that blue" is creating both positive and negative emotions.

Blue is ambiguous here.  It could refer to her eye color, and he could be so struck by her beauty that he is moved to these emotions.  However, it's also worth noting that "blue" is also a common way to refer to sadness, so it's possible he is reacting to her emotions. He could also be referring to his own emotions in reaction to her eyes.

As I said, ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

Given that it directly follows the line telling her to close her eyes, it's very likely that blue refers to eye colour.  Blue may be to emphasise the youth and innocence of the girl.

Mike Kozar's answer covers the meanings of high and low.  The singer gets high because he is having sexual thoughts about the girl, and low because she is underage and he knows acting on those thoughts would be a terrible idea.  Which is why he wants her to close her eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, these are lyrics, which are poetry, which is art; and the meaning of any piece of art lies within the beholder. But this is my interpretation:

The author of the lyrics  is playing around with the word "blue" here, and using it simultaneously for different meanings and even as different parts of speech.

"Blue" can be an adjective, as it is here describing both the color of the girl's eyes (see more on this in @ssav's excellent answer) and the author's sad feelings about being so attracted to this inappropriately under-aged girl (more about this in @Mike Kozar's also excellent answer).

"Blue" can also be a noun; and the same occurrence of the word, meaning both the color blue and the author's sad mood, acts as a subject noun here:

> That *(article)* blue *(subject)* is getting *(verb)* me *(object)* high *(adjective)*
>   And *(conjunction)* [that blue is] making *(verb)* me *(object)* low *(adjective)*

And "blue" can be a verb, but (and this is where your love/hate relationship with the English language may hit a very high/low point) it's not used that way here. Both meanings of "to blue" are chemical processes: one oxidizes the surface of steel to provide partial protection from rust; and one adds a slight blue tint to white laundry, making it the white appear brighter. Neither is going on in this song.

I think the author wants the little girl to close her eyes not just because they are so problematically blue, but also to shut him out, to decline the relationship he so desperately both wants and doesn't want to have with her. Some of the lyrics not quoted here include very sexual connotations and cultural references, and I think that by "eyes" the author might also mean "legs."

Answer (score -1):

After a person has died if not put into a coffin they will go blue I will explain more later but they are singing about a dead corpse